# How to implement partial normalization while keeping data integrity across documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, transaction, normalization

I've been researching how to properly design a mongo schema and came across this blog post on their site: http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87892923503/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-2

The idea for partial normalization for faster reads makes great sense but what I can't understand is how to implement such a pattern. Everything I've read about atomic updates says that mongo is no good at them, yet here we have a simple case where if one update goes through and the other does not, the data will be completely out of sync. If I wanted to use this pattern in my schema design how would I properly implement it to ensure data integrity? I've seen this article but it seems WAY to complex for what I want to obtain with simple normalization: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/

Comment: That "two-phase commit" is exactly what you would want to do to achieve what you are describing.

Comment: That article looks like a very difficult pattern to properly implement. Is there a library or something that can do it? Or through mongoose? It's very surprising I'd need to go that complex when the mongodb blog post glosses over it like it's just abother simple choice.

Comment: used mongoDb recently and came across similar issues. interested to know if people recommend trying to solve them, or is it a case of not following the NoSql pattern well enough?